# Gradle project sync completed with some errors

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My android app is nearing completion, but android studio now seems to be unusable. There are red lines everywhere and the message, "Gradle project sync completed with some errors." I've googled, I've watched youtube videos, but the studio version they're using is older than mine, the UI is different.

I have tried various solutions from SO and around the internet including building the project, changing from local gradle distribution to default wrapper; changing back again; unchecking all the boxes on the android sdk mangager and rechecking them, changing the classpath so that t matches the one in settings; changing it back. Everything is making this worse.

Now, when pressing run, it's showing me an edit configuration window, with the message, "Gradle project sync failed. Please fix your project and try again."

Honestly, I'm just using android-studio to write an app. I don't know how it works or what goes on behind the scenes. I'm a little over my head here.

build.gradle code:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.lp1"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
}
```

edit: changed  appcompat-v7:24.+' to appcompat-v7:24.2.0'

log now reads:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
[Fatal Error] appcompat-v7-24.2.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] recyclerview-v7-24.2.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] support-annotations-24.2.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0.
 Required by:
     Lp1:app:unspecified
     Lp1:app:unspecified > com.android.support:design:24.2.0
  > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0.
     > Could not parse POM /home/david/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/24.2.0/appcompat-v7-24.2.0.pom
        > Content is not allowed in prolog.
> Could not resolve com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0.
 Required by:
     Lp1:app:unspecified > com.android.support:design:24.2.0
  > Could not resolve com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0.
     > Could not parse POM /home/david/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/24.2.0/recyclerview-v7-24.2.0.pom
        > Content is not allowed in prolog.
  > Could not resolve com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0.
 Required by:
     Lp1:app:unspecified > com.android.support:design:24.2.0 > com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0 > com.android.support:support-compat:24.2.0
  > Could not resolve com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0.
     > Could not parse POM /home/david/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/24.2.0/support-annotations-24.2.0.pom
        > Content is not allowed in prolog.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 3.244 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: please, post your build.gradle code

Comment: Do you know what you changed between the code that could compile and now it doesn't? Besides modifying the wrapper and the SDKs?

Comment: I created a new empty scrolling activity. There were red lines everywhere - and then they started appearing in all other activities which had previously been fine. Deleted the new scrolling activity.

Comment: And your other `build.gradle`? `app/build.gradle`?

Comment: Can you please try to make `appcompat-v7:24.+'` to `appcompat-v7:24.2.0'`?

Comment: Are you using a proxy?